# How to use UserGroupInformation with Kerberos WebHDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, webhdfs

Following is the client code on non hadoop system to perform actions on the secured remote HDFS.

```
Configuration conf = new
        Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
conf.set("java.security.krb5.conf",krbPath);
conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "webhdfs://10.31.251.254:50070");
conf.set("fs.webhdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem.class.getName());
conf.set("com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule", "required");
conf.set("debug", "true");
conf.set("ticketCache", "DIR:/etc/");
System.out.print("Conf......");

UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);



UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("Dummy@EXAMPLE.COM", keytab);
System.out.print("Obtained......");
URI uri = URI.create("webhdfs://Dummy:50070");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(uri, conf);

if (fs.mkdirs(new Path("/testKerb2")))
    System.out.print("Directory created...");
```

I am able to perform the actions but the ticket configuration values are not read from krb5.conf. Ticket lifetime mentioned in conf file is 1m but the code generates a ticket with 1d lifetime. And also the tickets are not generated in configured ticketCache.

Please help in configuring so that code reads from krb5.conf file and generates tickets in configured path.

Following in the console o/p

```
*911 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - hadoop login commit
912 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - using kerberos user:hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM
914 [main] INFO org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - Login successful for user hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM using keytab file wcnew.keytab
Obtained......998 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryUtils  - multipleLinearRandomRetry = null
1026 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM (auth:KERBEROS) from:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$Runner.getHttpUrlConnection(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:456)
1027 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem  - open AuthenticatedURL connection
1051 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - Found tgt Ticket (hex) =
0000: 61 82 01 42 30 82 01 3E   A0 03 02 01 05 A1 0D 1B  a..B0..>........
0010: 0B 45 58 41 4D 50 4C 45   2E 43 4F 4D A2 20 30 1E  .EXAMPLE.COM. 0.
0020: A0 03 02 01 02 A1 17 30   15 1B 06 6B 72 62 74 67  .......0...krbtg
0030: 74 1B 0B 45 58 41 4D 50   4C 45 2E 43 4F 4D A3 82  t..EXAMPLE.COM..
0040: 01 04 30 82 01 00 A0 03   02 01 12 A1 03 02 01 01  ..0.............
0050: A2 81 F3 04 81 F0 EC 1A   94 3A 38 70 90 14 04 B5  .........:8p....
0060: 23 A5 0A 68 78 9E 52 74   A8 2C C2 98 8D FA 6F AD  #..hx.Rt.,....o.
0070: B1 8F 4A 69 02 B1 13 A0   8B 45 B1 51 1F 48 A6 2B  ..Ji.....E.Q.H.+
0080: 22 23 26 63 05 12 7F 1A   38 A9 81 0B 5B EA FA CC  "#&c....8...[...
0090: A7 D3 BC 15 37 46 32 2F   94 D4 A3 A4 88 9C 01 C5  ....7F2/........
00A0: 40 A5 83 CE 46 6B 6E 83   9E CD 8D DE A8 60 7F 77  @...Fkn......`.w
00B0: 3A 1D F4 E4 FB 26 E9 1F   D8 54 1E 78 0E 7C 15 8C  :....&...T.x....
00C0: 46 54 11 D9 69 F7 FD 65   F5 72 AB 48 75 B3 6E C1  FT..i..e.r.Hu.n.
00D0: 38 80 8C 72 62 CB 8F 55   F0 0C 3B BA 28 3B 74 3B  8..rb..U..;.(;t;
00E0: C7 BB F4 8F 81 FF 16 EA   D6 E1 42 5B A0 EE E6 13  ..........B[....
00F0: 8E 16 A3 0F F0 CE 0B 83   6D 5C E9 36 25 0C DF 8A  ........m\.6%...
0100: 09 76 41 86 2A CB B0 B6   19 58 6D 38 85 AD 94 92  .vA.*....Xm8....
0110: DE B8 44 D3 94 EC BB B7   DE D2 D3 DB 7E 32 03 06  ..D..........2..
0120: C2 CE 8D F5 36 AA DE E6   84 C6 FB F5 6A A9 D6 CF  ....6.......j...
0130: B9 20 0C F0 AB 56 3E 1E   9D 9E B5 BD 24 CD C1 DA  . ...V>.....$...
0140: AB AB B7 71 35 B4                                  ...q5.

Client Principal = hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM
Server Principal = krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
Session Key = EncryptionKey: keyType=17 keyBytes (hex dump)=
0000: 79 80 FD 99 CF 82 F2 76   C3 DE 1C 01 8A 78 EC 89  y......v.....x..


Forwardable Ticket true
Forwarded Ticket false
Proxiable Ticket false
Proxy Ticket false
Postdated Ticket false
Renewable Ticket false
Initial Ticket false
Auth Time = Tue Oct 07 03:46:09 UTC 2014
Start Time = Tue Oct 07 03:46:09 UTC 2014
End Time = Wed Oct 08 03:46:09 UTC 2014
Renew Till = null
Client Addresses  Null
Found ticket for hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM to go to krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM expiring on Wed Oct 08 03:46:09 UTC 2014
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 17 16 23 1 3.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=wckdserver.krbnet UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=680
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=wckdserver.krbnet UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=680
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=672
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove wckdserver.krbnet
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbApReq: APOptions are 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 637586272
Created InitSecContextToken:
0000: 01 00 6E 82 02 53 30 82   02 4F A0 03 02 01 05 A1  ..n..S0..O......
0010: 03 02 01 0E A2 07 03 05   00 20 00 00 00 A3 82 01  ......... ......
0020: 62 61 82 01 5E 30 82 01   5A A0 03 02 01 05 A1 0D  ba..^0..Z.......
0030: 1B 0B 45 58 41 4D 50 4C   45 2E 43 4F 4D A2 27 30  ..EXAMPLE.COM.'0
0040: 25 A0 03 02 01 00 A1 1E   30 1C 1B 04 48 54 54 50  %.......0...HTTP
0050: 1B 14 70 69 76 68 64 73   6E 65 2E 6C 6F 63 61 6C  ..pivhdsne.local
0060: 64 6F 6D 61 69 6E A3 82   01 19 30 82 01 15 A0 03  domain....0.....
0070: 02 01 12 A1 03 02 01 01   A2 82 01 07 04 82 01 03  ................
0080: 0C E0 CC 1B 75 0D 75 26   7E FC 33 D6 37 7D EC 09  ....u.u&..3.7...
0090: DA CE BE 9D 48 25 89 E4   9E F3 D0 07 13 CE 3D 96  ....H%........=.
00A0: E8 C2 0F 6E 8E 28 C7 85   3A D4 9D B8 CF 96 DD 3F  ...n.(..:......?
00B0: 42 8F 93 E3 E8 AD DB 84   51 02 E4 C6 BC F2 5D C5  B.......Q.....].
00C0: 17 73 9A B8 EC 10 76 58   6F F5 25 8D 5A C6 48 6B  .s....vXo.%.Z.Hk
00D0: A8 5A 30 83 14 F4 7D E0   90 FF D8 A8 A7 17 51 00  .Z0...........Q.
00E0: 43 0C 1D B6 2A C1 49 66   FA B8 5E 47 67 4B B0 FA  C...*.If..^GgK..
00F0: 10 C2 0D 72 BC 01 C5 D8   FD 5A 1F 8D 53 CA D9 88  ...r.....Z..S...
0100: 6C 00 7C 73 66 88 3A 41   35 B2 45 CF F5 19 8C 28  l..sf.:A5.E....(
0110: 87 C5 FC 4A E5 37 51 BA   8B E0 FF ED 69 03 2D 4E  ...J.7Q.....i.-N
0120: 3A E8 56 0A 84 92 98 95   E7 5B 15 DC 35 11 35 CF  :.V......[..5.5.
0130: F3 3A 99 6F C1 4A F5 49   62 E1 DC 0B FD F2 82 37  .:.o.J.Ib......7
0140: EE BB B8 85 78 50 1B 3A   E3 41 7D 96 2B 63 30 2A  ....xP.:.A..+c0*
0150: 70 C4 C3 D4 EA FF 1F F0   6A 9E BB 60 A2 A4 4D 3D  p.......j..`..M=
0160: 8E 48 57 12 10 A4 96 49   C2 1B AC 30 F7 3E 5A 98  .HW....I...0.>Z.
0170: CB D5 A0 F0 2F FB A4 F3   6D 3C 00 C5 F2 CC 32 BC  ..../...m<....2.
0180: F0 B1 04 A4 81 D3 30 81   D0 A0 03 02 01 11 A2 81  ......0.........
0190: C8 04 81 C5 58 E6 68 49   27 EA D0 A2 9A FB EA 70  ....X.hI'......p
01A0: 61 10 FD 7E 66 B5 EF 02   F0 DA 5E 3E C0 3B 53 72  a...f.....^>.;Sr
01B0: 77 1B 4C 69 7D 49 96 19   58 11 E7 FB DC BE 6B 3D  w.Li.I..X.....k=
01C0: BD 47 24 49 E9 01 7D A3   AD 14 1C 92 94 8A BE 71  .G$I...........q
01D0: AE 60 FB 8B F9 29 26 6E   49 27 8F F9 BA EC ED 77  .`...)&nI'.....w
01E0: 4E F1 E2 E7 9C F6 79 57   9D 95 6C 6D 28 B5 43 F3  N.....yW..lm(.C.
01F0: A2 03 CE DF 3D 0F FE 2E   F8 63 B5 F5 C8 D9 A7 77  ....=....c.....w
0200: 79 53 80 90 DD B9 7C 50   06 F3 84 B5 CE 90 6F 8D  yS.....P......o.
0210: 71 3B EF A0 7A CC 8D 2E   7E 25 DE ED EE F8 1C D2  q;..z....%......
0220: 41 DD BE 05 26 A0 1B 19   BF 58 7B 8E 87 C4 AC EF  A...&....X......
0230: 8D 66 C6 AF C9 42 3B E8   A8 A1 8E 80 D4 3F E7 9D  .f...B;......?..
0240: 58 D8 F2 53 A7 62 C0 70   84 21 5E C2 85 BC 86 70  X..S.b.p.!^....p
0250: ED CC 78 0A 52 D2 F3 EB   B1                       ..x.R....

1566 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator  - Using fallback authenticator sequence.
Found ticket for hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM to go to krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM expiring on Wed Oct 08 03:46:09 UTC 2014
Entered Krb5Context.initSecContext with state=STATE_NEW
Service ticket not found in the subject
>>> Credentials acquireServiceCreds: same realm
Using builtin default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes
default etypes for default_tgs_enctypes: 17 16 23 1 3.
>>> CksumType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.RsaMd5CksumType
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbKdcReq send: kdc=wckdserver.krbnet UDP:88, timeout=30000, number of retries =3, #bytes=680
>>> KDCCommunication: kdc=wckdserver.krbnet UDP:88, timeout=30000,Attempt =1, #bytes=680
>>> KrbKdcReq send: #bytes read=672
>>> KdcAccessibility: remove wckdserver.krbnet
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
>>> KrbApReq: APOptions are 00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000
>>> EType: sun.security.krb5.internal.crypto.Aes128CtsHmacSha1EType
Krb5Context setting mySeqNumber to: 464503906
Created InitSecContextToken:
0000: 01 00 6E 82 02 53 30 82   02 4F A0 03 02 01 05 A1  ..n..S0..O......
0010: 03 02 01 0E A2 07 03 05   00 20 00 00 00 A3 82 01  ......... ......
0020: 62 61 82 01 5E 30 82 01   5A A0 03 02 01 05 A1 0D  ba..^0..Z.......
0030: 1B 0B 45 58 41 4D 50 4C   45 2E 43 4F 4D A2 27 30  ..EXAMPLE.COM.'0
0040: 25 A0 03 02 01 00 A1 1E   30 1C 1B 04 48 54 54 50  %.......0...HTTP
0050: 1B 14 70 69 76 68 64 73   6E 65 2E 6C 6F 63 61 6C  ..pivhdsne.local
0060: 64 6F 6D 61 69 6E A3 82   01 19 30 82 01 15 A0 03  domain....0.....
0070: 02 01 12 A1 03 02 01 01   A2 82 01 07 04 82 01 03  ................
0080: EB 9C 24 60 E8 63 A6 EF   E8 9C B7 DB 4B 0B DB A0  ..$`.c......K...
0090: 47 01 B0 C3 DF 50 96 3E   76 D3 36 14 62 CC 14 3D  G....P.>v.6.b..=
00A0: 5D 06 07 2C F8 E7 79 09   A6 73 4A 2C D5 2D 6F 09  ]..,..y..sJ,.-o.
00B0: 08 C2 A0 85 B7 AF D3 3E   BE 83 F5 11 62 21 4F 5C  .......>....b!O\
00C0: 73 09 A2 8F 4A CD 3F 4C   31 46 6E C5 98 C6 5D EF  s...J.?L1Fn...].
00D0: 37 B3 50 C6 D4 18 82 62   65 6A 0D 0C 71 EA 96 16  7.P....bej..q...
00E0: E7 9A E8 4C CA 90 0A 3D   FD 03 C1 ED 3F 85 5B C7  ...L...=....?.[.
00F0: 3A 15 F7 52 95 58 D5 07   3D 0C 93 8B 63 C7 CA 19  :..R.X..=...c...
0100: 29 3D 68 BF 58 B6 5C 48   26 31 06 31 1B A1 AF 3C  )=h.X.\H&1.1...<
0110: FD 98 BE 75 46 42 06 70   C6 74 B2 1C DC CC 13 AE  ...uFB.p.t......
0120: C0 D2 BB 78 EF 36 21 25   7C 06 20 91 3A 59 99 D1  ...x.6!%.. .:Y..
0130: F0 D3 0C 5A 5F E6 27 98   C5 FD 56 98 83 22 94 4E  ...Z_.'...V..".N
0140: 32 1F 5E 55 C5 07 CA 27   AE C2 0B B9 8F 33 06 05  2.^U...'.....3..
0150: 6B 84 9C 16 9D 30 D1 8A   AB F7 79 7A 9F 7C 11 5E  k....0....yz...^
0160: 81 7F 63 FC C2 49 B0 2F   13 2C B9 00 24 A0 44 DD  ..c..I./.,..$.D.
0170: 06 56 3E BF 16 15 14 DD   C2 5B 63 8E DC F8 63 30  .V>......[c...c0
0180: 6A C0 E6 A4 81 D3 30 81   D0 A0 03 02 01 11 A2 81  j.....0.........
0190: C8 04 81 C5 8D 4D DD 54   F7 22 23 7F AC 89 E6 25  .....M.T."#....%
01A0: 1C E0 95 26 DB D0 FD 01   5F 0F C2 51 98 AC 0A FA  ...&...._..Q....
01B0: 74 56 BF 1E C0 A6 B6 1F   B8 7F E7 EC B1 54 1C DD  tV...........T..
01C0: CB BA 33 58 7D 13 86 84   0A 83 2D B1 5D 96 D8 B2  ..3X......-.]...
01D0: AF 01 CA 5D 94 BE 38 E9   D0 75 4E 2E C6 16 4C BD  ...]..8..uN...L.
01E0: C0 45 9C 85 A7 A7 35 6A   81 AC 10 8F EF F9 D1 A5  .E....5j........
01F0: 72 9E 76 93 F5 98 B6 25   E2 17 B8 59 7E 55 26 95  r.v....%...Y.U&.
0200: 36 EF 1D 2E 7F 6B 1C 26   46 BF DB 4D 48 31 86 4B  6....k.&F..MH1.K
0210: 9D CC 67 8B 71 D5 24 8E   C4 42 1D 99 0B C0 7B 6E  ..g.q.$..B.....n
0220: 44 ED 8E B0 1B BA D5 AE   41 E5 9A 2A 30 36 91 38  D.......A..*06.8
0230: 7D BA 47 FC 61 64 53 49   68 75 AC CA 13 DC B6 8B  ..G.adSIhu......
0240: 0E E4 84 3F 61 7B 6E 71   4E 5F B1 56 17 AA 70 61  ...?a.nqN_.V..pa
0250: 0F EF 8C C7 CB 45 BA 01   64                       .....E..d

1898 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.token.Token  - Cannot find class for token kind WEBHDFS delegation
1899 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil  - Acquired token Kind: WEBHDFS delegation, Service: xxxx:50070, Ident: 00 04 68 64 66 73 04 68 64 66 73 00 8a 01 48 e8 b9 be 33 8a 01 49 0c c6 42 33 8d 04 d5 6c 8f 99
1904 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem  - Created new DT for xxxx:50070
1908 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM (auth:KERBEROS) from:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$Runner.getHttpUrlConnection(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:456)
1908 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem  - open URL connection
Directory created...2921 [main] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation  - PrivilegedAction as:hdfs/YYYY@EXAMPLE.COM (auth:KERBEROS) from:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.WebHdfsFileSystem$Runner.getHttpUrlConnection(WebHdfsFileSystem.java:456)*
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the location of the krb5.conf file in the System, not the Hadoop configurations, i.e. replace your line

```
conf.set("java.security.krb5.conf",krbPath);
```

with

```
System.setProperty( "java.security.krb5.conf", krbPath);
```

(but you probably figured this out yourself, given that the question is 5 months old)